# MSSQL percentage calculation not consistent

Tags: percentage

I need to calculate the percentage of growth between two numbers.
In the examples below the start value is the first and the current value is the second.
When I try the following queries the results are not as expected (by me).

`SELECT ( CAST (68 as float) / CAST (1 as float) * 100)
--current value 68, start value 1, the percentage of growth is 68%
--MSSQL is giving the result 6800, which is 100 times too high`

`SELECT ( CAST (30 as float) / CAST (10 as float) * 100)
--current value 30, start value 10, the percentage of growth is 300%
--MSSQL is giving the result 300, which makes sense`

`SELECT ( CAST (20 as float) / CAST (40 as float) * 100)
--current value 20, start value 40, the percentage of growth is -50%
--MSSQL is giving the result 50, which somewhat makes sense`

Which query should I use to get a consistent output for each situation so I can use it for proper display in a graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is calculating it correctly. Your percentage growth calculations (your comments) look odd.

E.g. your first example: start value 68, current value 1. (68/1)*100 = 6800. If you want 68% growth, then  your start value would need to be 1.68, not 68, which would make start value 168% of current value. I.E. it's grown by 68%.

Your third example: (20/40)*100 = (1/2)*100 = 50. The start value is half that of the current value, so 50% is correct.

Comment: I had the current and starting values in the comments reversed, fixed this now. But am still wondering which single query I can use for all three value scenario'.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now.
1 growing to 68 is indeed really 6800%.
I though this was only 68% :-).

Thanks for the answer!